# Default C# ASP.NET nav bar resizing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP so I am still trying to find me way around. I am running into a problem where the default nav bar that came with the project is resizing over the content if I change the width of the window.

Default Project meaning: In VS13 create a new ASP.NET Web Forms project. The Navigation that comes as a template with that project is what I stared with. Simply add a few more links to the default and you can see the resizing issue I am having.

I can't figure out how to change the padding of the content when the top nav bar resizes.

Examples:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

How do I stop this from happening?

Edit: Code from Site.Master

```
<form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Winded Warriors</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Players">Players</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Stats">Stats</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/MatchHistory">Match History</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Schedule">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Photos">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/WindedWarriors"><img src="http://www.windedwarriors.com/facebook-icon.png" height="16"></a> </li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCudcTnN9fHNLigUTvmGv_Fg"><img src="http://www.windedwarriors.com/YouTube-icon.png" height="16"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- why doesnt this not space correctly???? -->
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Winded Warriors Soccer</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Files:
bootstrap.css http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=22346182312171777192
Site.css http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=24528713647080441261

Comment: And how would we reproduce this issue?

Comment: Also, what exactly is "the default nav bar that came with the project", what project? Whose project?

Comment: When creating a new project in visual studio 2013, creating a Web Forms ASP.NET project has a template page that includes the nav bar seen above. All I did was change the links

Comment: Post the code, some of us do not have VS2013 installed here :c

Comment: Please post the CSS file. Or at the least post the CSS for container and body-content.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to be that there is a float not being cleared after the navigation div, or that the navigation div is using position:absolute.

Without seeing the html/css I cannot tell you for certain.

Answer (score 0):

In the aspx assign an ID to the first div

```
<div id="myNavBar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

then you can write the following JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function autocollapse() {
            var navbar = $('#myNavBar');
            navbar.removeClass('collapsed'); 
            if (navbar.innerHeight() > 50)
                navbar.addClass('collapsed'); // collapse mode
        }
    $(document).on('ready', autocollapse);
    $(window).on('resize', autocollapse);
</script>
```

you can change the 50 in the `navbar.innerHeight() > 50` line to the actual height of your navbar in the first image